# Programatic Full Import in Solr using Java

Tags: java, solr

I need to do a full-import with Java to a solr server.

I am trying it this way:

```
SolrServer srv = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(Settings.getInstance().getSolrURL());
SolrParams s = new SolrQuery("data?command=full-import");
srv.request(new QueryRequest(s));
```

but it does not work.
The query executed is

```
params={q=data?command%3Dfull-import&wt=javabin&version=1} hits=0 status=0 QTime=1
```

So it is actually seeking "data?command=full-import".

Do you know a way to do it programmaticaly in Java?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at [DataImportScheduler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Scheduling). The source is there, in the wiki. It periodically invokes full or delta import.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [ModifiableSolrParams](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/common/params/ModifiableSolrParams.html) object to accomplish this.

```
SolrServer solr = new CommonsHttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("qt", "/dataimport");
params.set("command", "full-import");

QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
```

Comment: Thanx Joel
I actually made a mistake, the query I needed is actually

  http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import

Using your suggestion (replacing data with dataimport) the query String is like:

  http://localhost:8983/solr/qt=%2Fdataimport&command=full-import

Is there a way to do this with ModifiableSolrParams?

Thank you!